# Refactor a function in MATLAB to accept originally scalar argument as an array

Tags: matlab, function, refactoring

Imagine you have a function in MATLAB of two variables, `f(x,y)`. And it was written in a way that `x` can be a scalar or a 1D array, but `y` is strictly meant to be a scalar. For an array `x` the function returns the array of elements of the same length as `x`.

Next, you need to refactor this function to accept both `x` and `y` to be 1D arrays of equal length, the value of a function `f([x1,x1],[y1,y2]) = [f(x1,y1), f(x2,y2)]`.

How would you do this in the most efficient way?

Comment: You should put more effort to explain the problem and provide us with what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly suited for `arrayfun`:

```
f = @(x,y) y*x.^2; %an example where y should not be an array, x can
fnew = @(xv,yv) arrayfun(f,xv,yv);
```

This new function will return `f(xv(k),yv(k))` for each `k` as long as the two arrays are of the same size.

Note that `arrayfun` is quite slow, so using a loop to the same effect or implementing the vectorization for the specific function `f` (possibly making use of `bsxfun`) might be faster.

The explicit looping alternative would be

```
function fv=fnew(xv,yv)

if numel(xv)~=numel(yv)
  exit('fnew> xv and yv should have same length');
end

fv=zeros(size(xv));
for k=1:numel(xv)
  fv(k) = f(xv(k),yv(k));
end
```

You can spare some runtime by skipping the size check, similar checks are the reason why `arrayfun` tends to be slower.